# In Magento 2,I can't Open Categories With New URL

Tags: magento2, category, url

[image]

If I add new URL then it's showing 404 error when it open frontend side.If it open with old URL it's working.

For Ex. I have added new URL "business-card-gift-card-holders123" for category.It's showing the error When It open. Other Side it category is open with old URL. "business-card-gift-card-holders".

I have select "No" from below Path

> Store -> configuration->catalog->catalog->Search Engine Optimization
>   ->Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed

Answer (score 1):

While the checkbox is disabled it has no effect.
The checkbox becomes enabled only if you change something in the url key.
And it has effect only when saving the product/category.
In case you change the url key, it will change the records associated to the old url key in the `url_rewrite` table and it will create new url redirects in the same table from he old url to the new url.
I'm not sure I understand exactly what you need, but I have a feeling that you understood its purpose wrong. (also, my assumption can be wrong).
In case you assume that the state is saved on the product/category itself and it has effect on the behavior of the url rewrites... it doesn't.
It is strictly used to manage url rewrites when the product/category is saved.

Comment: I want to categories open with new URL, Which I added in URL Key.